# Data Engineering, ETL, SQL Server Integration Services(SSIS) resources form beginner to pro level

Tags: sql

I am a fresh Ph.D. student in information science. I know some python, C, Cobol, etc.
I know some sites to learn SQL for data science interviews.

Can anybody tell me any resource available for data engineering, ETL, SSIS which teach from the beginner to pro level?

Comment: Yea it is hard to find proper information about it, which is weird seeing SSIS is so damn useful. Currently teaching it to college kids who just started out and half of them are in love with it.

Comment: SSIS is lovely. I got to know it during my internship... I want to learn and master it!!